# Get the value from inside the row html in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a database table that I'm outputting onto a internal webpage. I need to find the value of a selected row so I can then merge the rows and send the value back to the db so it knows which rows to merge.

When clicking on a button to merge rows this is my function I have created:

```
    //merge the rows now
    function mergeTheRows() {
        //get value from each row
        $("#mergeRowsBody tr").each(function() {
            rowValue = document.getElementsByTagName("tr").value;
            mergeRowsArray.push(rowValue);
            console.log(mergeRowsArray);
        });
     }
```

Here is the body of the table (I'm only showing two rows for the example):

```
<tbody id="mergeRowsBody">
  <tr class="rowEditData odd mergeSelect" value="110461" role="row">
    <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">ABBEVILLE</td>
    <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">South Carolina</td>
    <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
    <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
    <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">001</td>
    <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">39</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="rowEditData even mergeSelect" value="107045" role="row">
    <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">Abbeville County</td>
    <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">South Carolina</td>
    <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">001</td>
    <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">45</td>
    <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
    <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
```

I keep getting undefined when it console logs to the browser. I've tried finding the value by ID and class as well, but it keeps saying undefined. What am I doing wrong?

All I need is to be able to save the ID of the row so I can then let the database know which rows will be merged.

Comment: Nenad and Vladu's answers both work great. This is the time I wish I could choose both answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `data-` property instead of `value`, value is for inputs, selects... Also you need to add `table` in your html and then you can use `map()` and `get()` to return array of `data-values`.

```js
var mergeRowsArray = $("#mergeRowsBody tr").map(function() {
  return $(this).data('value')
}).get();

console.log(mergeRowsArray)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="mergeRowsBody">
    <tr class="rowEditData odd mergeSelect" data-value="110461" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">ABBEVILLE</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">South Carolina</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">001</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">39</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData even mergeSelect" data-value="107045" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">Abbeville County</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">South Carolina</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">001</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">45</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

[getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/ro/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) returns a live HTMLCollection of elements with the given tag name.

```
rowValue = document.getElementsByTagName("tr").value;
```

replace with

```
rowValue =$(this).attr("value");
```

Comment: I've tried using ById and ByClassName and those don't work either. I'm not sure why I can't pull out the value. I've done it before. Does it have something to do with it being inside an .each function?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using just jQuery?

```
rowValue = $(".mergeSelect").val();
```

Comment: Yes I have and it still says undefined

Comment: @JBaldwin sorry my review was a mistake. :(